# Animated ScrollView in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[image]

I want the icons to be in a scroll view and I am unable to achieve that

Comment: Which icons? What did you try? What exactly was the problem?

Comment: the icons above the swipe up categories